# Swift: Image view display wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have `UIImageView` with constraint look like picture
[TableviewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJbXn.png)

but when set image from array Data, it's display wrong (outside of imageView)
[Image display wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHBjQ.png)

i've set in tableView

```
cell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
cell.imgView.clipsToBounds = true
if self.arrDulieu[indexPath.row].attachment?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
   cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: self.arrDulieu[indexPath.row].attachment![0])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `imgView` (property of the custom class) not `imageView` (property of the `UITableViewCell` class)

```
cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: self.arrDulieu[indexPath.row].attachment![0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image on main thread

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.arrDulieu[indexPath.row].attachment?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: self.arrDulieu[indexPath.row].attachment![0])
        } 
    }
```

Comment: this won't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Please check your constraints if you are using storyboard.
If still facing the issue, please post your full code so that the problem get understood properly.
Thank You!

@Sh_Khan fixed the issue.